# rename resource when import

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have a big robot framework project, with different resources and keywords in different folders.

I found a problem right now when I'm trying to merge all this test.

in my testsuite, I import some resources and all of them are used and some of them have the same keyword, I need to rename to execute the one I want to:

```
Resource   tests/test1/Keyword/CommonKeywords.robot
Resource   tests/test2/Keyword/CommonKeywords.robot

*** Keyword ***
Check values
   Application Login #it exist in both, I want to use the one from test1
```

I saw there's a posibility to use WITH NAME but only for libraries. Does it exist something similar? this is what I tried:

```
Resource   tests/test1/Keyword/CommonKeywords.robot  WITH NAME  test1
Resource   tests/test2/Keyword/CommonKeywords.robot  WITH NAME  test2

*** Keyword ***
Check values
   test1.Application Login
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now Robot framework does not Support WITH NAME on Resource Files but there was a question asked about this 4 years ago, and the thread has been active fairly recently.

As Stated here [Offical github robot topics](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2104) This post is very recent. You should keep a look out on this one.

The functionality you are looking for "Is a nice to have, but not highest priority" as stated by @pekkaklarck

> I still see this as a nice to have but not too high priority feature.
>   That means I won't implement it myself in the foreseeable future, but
>   I would be super happy to review and merge PR if someone else finds
>   this more important.